# SQL Server 2000: Invalid operator for data type. Operator equals add, type equals ntext

Tags: sql-server-2000

I have a stored procedure which gets `Ntext` parameters. Inside the stored procedure, I have a `varchar` variable and I set this `varchar` variable by concatenating few strings.

I get the following error at this point, while compiling.

> Invalid operator for data type. Operator equals add, type
>   equals ntext.

Can someone help?

Comment: show us some code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a careless Mistake. I was actually concatenation my `varchar` variable with the `ntext` variable. As `Ntext` concatenation is not allowed, I got stuck.