# Multiple Values in DropdownList.DataTextField Not Working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the below code which is populating a dropdownlist in ASP.NET. When I use a single value, everything works like a charm, but I want the DataTextField to use two fields coming from the database, not one. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I have tried several ways, but nothing seems to work :(

```
    Dim connstr As String = Session("ConnStrEP")
    Using con As New SqlConnection(connstr)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand()
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.CommandText = "GetWaivers"
            cmd.Connection = con
            con.Open()
            Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            dr.Read()
            Code.DataSource = dr
            Code.DataTextField = String.Format("{0}, {1}", Code.SelectedValue("tblWVCode").ToString(), Code.SelectedValue("tblWVDesc").ToString())
            Code.DataValueField = "tblWVDesc"
            Code.DataBind()
            dr.Close()
            con.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
```

UPDATE:
I generated the below SQL, but I am receiving an error when I execute the SQL Server 2008 Stored Procedure. "Invalid operator for data type. Operator equals add, type equals ntext.
"

```
SELECT TblWvCode, TblWvDesc, (TblWvCode + ' - ' + TblWvDesc) As FullList FROM EP.dbo.WaiverVarianceTbl
```

Comment: see this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367431/sql-server-2000-invalid-operator-for-data-type-operator-equals-add-type-equal

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, you'll need to change your SQL query to return the field on the format you need. `DataTextField` must be a field or property name.

Your query should looks like this

```
SELECT 
   TblWvCode, 
   TblWvDesc,
   (
      CAST(TblWvCode as nvarchar(max)) + ', ' + CAST(tblWVDesc as nvarchar(max))
   ) as FullList 
FROM EP.dbo.WaiverVarianceTbl
```

and then your VB code would be something like this

```
Code.DataTextField = "FullList"
Code.DataValueField = "tblWVDesc"
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the stored proc to concatenate the tblWVCode and tblWVDesc values and return them in a new field, you can then use that field for the DataTextField